# Garbage Collector unexpected output

Tags: java, garbage-collection, runtime, output, println

I can't understand what's happening here

```
public class UnderstandGC {
public class Inner1
{
    String name=new Inner2().name;
    public void finalize()
    {
        System.out.println("Inner1 -> I am Dead");
    }
}
public class Inner2
{
    public String name="Inner2";
    public void finalize()
    {
        System.out.println("Inner2 -> I am Dead");
    }
}
public void finalize()
{
    System.out.println("Main -> I am Dead");
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UnderstandGC ugc=new UnderstandGC();
Inner1 inner1=ugc.new Inner1();
//System.out.println("hello");      //1

Runtime.getRuntime().gc();         


    }
}
```

Output expected:
`Inner2 -> I am Dead` bcoz object of Inner2 instantiated as field reference in Inner1 has no local references from the main thread runtime stack.

Output Observed:  **nothing**

The interesting observation is if I include comment `//1` in my code it works fine. Can't understand what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`gc()` method javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#gc%28%29) states

> Calling this method suggests that the Java virtual machine expend
>   effort toward recycling unused objects in order to make the memory
>   they currently occupy available for quick reuse.

There is no guarantee that it will run the GC in either case.

Comment: Agreeing with the statement but it works every time if I add //1 . Have tested myself over 10 times.

Comment: @user2653926 That might just be because of how your JVM is implemented. Writing to standard output may cause that. A million other things may cause it too. You should not depend on it, ever.

Comment: Ok last question "IS Println auto flushing " that means it happens synchronously

Comment: @user This the `PrintStream#println()` in `System.out.println` flushes eagerly, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Tested by adding the following

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();     
    for(int i=0;i<25000;i++){

    }
```

On my JVM anything less than 25000 on the loop, does not call the gc, it seems to not even give a chance for the JVM to invoke the gc, even if it wanted too. I am speculating that the System.out.println gives the JVM just enough time to call the gc (again, only if it wants too as it is not guaranteed), before the application ends.

Comment: That is something I can't understand if println is synchronous .. how does it give time.. Your statement is true for //1 after calling gc() and it works too but for //1 before gc, the explanation is not satisfactory

Comment: The gc is and independent daemon thread, while the application is executing the println statement the gc is invoked.